# Use "perl6" command with Git Bash on windows

Tags: windows, git-bash, raku

Using Windows, I installed [Rakudo Star](https://rakudo.org/files) and Git and ensured that `C:\rakudo\bin` and `C:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\bin` are in my Path environment variable.

Now, typing `perl6` inside Git Bash afterwards gives the `command not found` error, **while the command does work** inside `powershell` and `cmd`. Typing `echo $PATH` inside Git Bash confirms again that the folders above are in my path variable here as well.

How can I get the `perl6` command working inside Git Bash?

**Note:** Using `moar` (moar.exe) which resides in the same folder as `perl6` works as well in Git Bash. Also hitting Tab show the autocomplete suggestion for `moar`, it does not do that for `perl6`.

Comment: Note that Rakudo recently, switched to a proper `perl6` binary, ie this problem will solve itself in the not too distant future

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash doesn't run Windows batch files, so you'll have to work around that.

An easy solution might be to add something like this you your `.bashrc`:

```
alias perl6='cmd /c perl6.bat'
```

Alternatively, you can convert `perl6.bat` to a shell script and put it somewhere in your `$PATH`.
I use the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/cygdrive/c/rakudo/bin:/cygdrive/c/rakudo/share/perl6/site/bin:$PATH
unset HOME

moar --execname="$0" \
     --libpath='C:\rakudo\share\nqp\lib' \
     --libpath='C:\rakudo\share\perl6\lib' \
     --libpath='C:\rakudo\share\perl6\runtime' \
     'C:\rakudo\share\perl6\runtime\perl6.moarvm' \
     "$@"
```

This is using Cygwin; you may need to adapt it a bit for Git bash (I don't know, no experience with it).

Alternatively, if you're using Windows 10, I can recommend installing WSL, and using perl6 in a WSL bash prompt instead.  This runs much smoother for me than the Windows version under Cygwin.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to install `perl6` from the link you provided and I can confirm the same behavior on Cygwin on Windows 10.

If I type in the Cygwin terminal window:

```
$ perl6
-bash: perl6: command not found
$ echo  $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/cygdrive/c/Users/Bruker/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/cygdrive/c/rakudo/bin:/cygdrive/c/rakudo/share/perl6/site/bin
$ cd /cygdrive/c/rakudo/bin
$ ls -l
-rwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM  930663 May 11  2017 libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
-rwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM  136146 Mar 30 20:55 libmoar.dll.a
-rwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM   56978 May 11  2017 libwinpthread-1.dll
-rwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM 7021172 Mar 30 20:55 moar.dll
-rwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM   64066 Mar 30 20:55 moar.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM     126 Mar 30 20:56 nqp.bat
-rwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM     126 Mar 30 20:56 nqp-m.bat
-rwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM     242 Mar 30 20:56 perl6.bat
-rwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM     248 Mar 30 20:56 perl6-debug-m.bat
-rwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM     242 Mar 30 20:56 perl6-m.bat
$ cat perl6.bat
@ "C:\rakudo\bin\moar" --execname="%~dpf0" --libpath="C:\rakudo\share\nqp\lib" --libpath="C:\rakudo\share\nqp\lib" --libpath="C:\rakudo\share/perl6/lib" --libpath="C:\rakudo\share/perl6/runtime" C:\rakudo\share\perl6\runtime\perl6.moarvm %*
```

Notice that the paths in the bat file are not [cygwin paths](http://xahlee.info/mswin/cygwin_path_windows_conversion.html). So that might explain why it does not work..

For example:

```
$ "C:\rakudo\bin\moar"
-bash: C:\rakudo\bin\moar: command not found
$  /cygdrive/c/rakudo/bin/moar
ERROR: Missing input file.

USAGE: moar [--crash] [--libpath=...] input.moarvm [program args]
       moar --dump input.moarvm
       moar --help
[...]
```

**Update**:

I also tried install [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/), and then from the MINGW64 terminal window:

```
$ echo $PATH
/c/Users/Bruker/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Bruker/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Users/Bruker/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
$ PATH=/c/rakudo/bin:$PATH
$ perl6
bash: perl6: command not found
$ moar
ERROR: Missing input file.
USAGE: moar [--crash] [--libpath=...] input.moarvm [program args]
       moar --dump input.moarvm
       moar --help
[...]
```

Note that `moar` is an `.exe` file while `perl6` is a `.bat` file.

Also it seems `perl6` is not "offical" for Cygwin yet according to [this issue](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2807).

Comment: Can you check if the `x` file permission is set for the batch file?

Comment: @Christoph See my updated answer. It looks like it is set: `-rwxrwx---+`

Comment: It does look like Git Bash just can't run .bat files and is unable to see them as executables, which is the problem. Running `perl6` from Git Bash will probably require a .sh file instead.

Comment: @JessicaNowak I think I found a workaround: you can run `perl6` from the Cygwin og Git Bash terminal using this command: `cmd "/c perl6 --version"`